# Getting Internship with Spotty Work History

Tags: resume, internship, applications, work-experience, developer

I'm currently **unemployed**.

For reference, [**Here's my Resume:**](http://codepen.io/edsonmendieta/pen/ZBrWKa) (Left out other short-term jobs from 2011 - 2013.)

In **September 2015** I started a 4-quarter long front-end Web-development certificate program at a local university.

I completed two quarters before I exited the program at the end of **March** of this year (**2016**) as a result of the remaining cost, coupled with the realization that I could continue my education for free online.

**January** and **February**, I worked as a packaging assistant for two months before being let go after the trial period. They said I just wasn't what they needed at that moment (did my work every day and it wasn't a corporate company, so I just took it for what it was and didn't look back).

**Since March** (when I exited school) I haven't had a job, but have been living off some money I had in savings and going through FreeCodeCamp's front-end development track.

I have now completed one of the final projects and will continue to complete the rest.

After looking at some web development **unpaid** and **paid** internship postings in my area, it seems I meet the knowledge requirements for a couple of them:

-HTML
-CSS
-Javascript
-Photoshp
-Portfolio with work examples

However, would my lack of steady work experience be a huge factor when applying to the **unpaid** internship?

What about the **paid** one?

If so, should I get a regular full-time or part-time job in something, simply to build some work experience? And if so, for how long (3 months, 6 months)?

**Or**, should I just try and go for the internships, doing my best to sell myself, **since** working at an un-related job, at a time when I have the skills for an internship might be redundant / unnecessary **at this point in time**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your academic and professional background is non-traditional for both getting an internship (you are not enrolled as a student) or getting a job as a developer (you do not have a bachelor's degree). This may make it difficult but not impossible to get either.  If this is something you want though you should try anyway. You should focus on demonstrating your skills and your dedication to a career in software to potential companies.  An internship can be a good way to do this. A portfolio on GitHub or similar site can also help. Industry certifications and reading up on current trends are also helpful.

In short, expect it to be difficult but you can't succeed without trying. Be prepared to interview at several companies and learn from your unsuccessful attempts.

Comment: Thanks Eric, good to know, I really appreciate it. This is along the lines of what I felt is the case, and I do have a github that I've been push all my exercise solutions and projects I build to so I'm glad for that. Also, I'm currently about to redo my portfolio site. Yeah, it seems that a heavy focus on these things and skills is the best route. Thanks for your feedback!